# Assign derived class to base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, variable-assignment

Is it safe to do the following or is it undefined behaviour:

```
class Base
{
private:
    int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    int b;
};

Base x;
Derived y;
x = y;   // safe?
```

Do the extra bits in derived classes just get sliced off?

Comment: Nothing gets "sliced off" here: `y` remains a fully valid object of type `Derived`. But only those parts of  `y` are assigned to `x`, that fit into `x`. That again is not a problem. It only becomes a problem, if you later assumes, that `x` is not of type `Base`, but of type `Derived`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right, the object is sliced. This is a [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) problem. You shouldn't do it!

Comment: This is not a "problem", it's a language feature and very useful one. For example, if you have data only struct where some values are specified and other values must be computed then you can put computed values in derived class.

Comment: @ShitalShah Most people find out about this feature the hard way but I agree it can be useful. My question would be if you were to use it how would you make it obvious to the reader of your code that this is your intention? I for one would always assume it was a bug unless there was a comment saying "Deliberately slicing the object".

Answer (score 12):

Yes, slicing occurs. It is not undefined behaviour though.

You might find this entry in the C++-FAQ helpful:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8